# Error 438 on getting information from Twitter by using VBA XMLHTTP getElementsByClassName()

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, twitter

I have limited knowledge on Excel VBA programming. 
Failed to get data from Twitter by using VBA XMLHTTP `getelementsbyClassName ()` which always result in error 438.

```
ss1 = HTML.getElementsByClassName("css-1dbjc4n r-1oszu61 r-1niwhzg r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-2llsf r-13qz1uu")
```

result in error message:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

`HTML.all` did work but if I used `getElementsbyClassName`, it failed.

```
Sub Fetch_Twit_1()    
    Dim HTML1 As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, ss1 As Object, URL$

    URL = "https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")             
        .Open "GET", URL, False        
        .send

        Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")

        If .Status = 200 Then        
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText        
        Else: MsgBox "Error"
        End If

        ss1 = HTML.getElementsByClassName("css-1dbjc4n r-1oszu61 r-1niwhzg r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-2llsf r-13qz1uu")

        For Each element In ss1        
            ActiveCell.Value = element.innerText        
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = element.ID        
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select        
        Next element

        Set HTML = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend to make use of the Twitter API otherwise your code will break everytime Twitter changes something on their website.

Comment: `ss1` needs to be `set`. This `HTML.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of objects, which is an object itself. So `ss1` needs to be declared and `set` accordingly.

Comment: Scraping the Twitter website like this is against the Terms of Service and may lead to your IP address being blocked. Use the official API.

Comment: Also, why use this `Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")` when you have already declared and instantiated an HTMLDocument object called HTML1?